# Why doesn't smooth "smooth completely"?

Tags: mesh, cloth-simulation

I have a plane, subdivided at 10, with sub-D modifier at 2. Smoothing is turned on. When warped as cloth, why can I still see individual polys which are bent from others at less than a 90-degree angle?

Comment: I would think not enough subdivisions in your plane. I would try more cuts than 10 depending on how large the plane is. Maybe 20 to 30.

Comment: Cloth needs _a lot_ of subdivisions to look decent. A subsurf modifier will not satisfy this requirement because cloth sim is applied to the base mesh only. You will need to either apply the subsurf or subdivide the mesh more. Then you can place another subsurf after the cloth modifier, with smoothing on to get a smooth surface. I would suggest caching the cloth and saving your file before you apply the subsurf. It can get pretty big if you're not careful.

Comment: I added the Smooth Modifier and this did the trick. 10 subdivisions x 2 sub-surface is plenty, with the Smooth Modifier.

Comment: @Italic_  You don't need to apply the subsurf, just put it above the cloth sim in the modifier stack.